# How to convert ARKit captured frame's CVPixelBuffer colorspace to RGB

Tags: swift, arkit, metal, coreml, cvpixelbuffer

I want to use coreML with vision for my trained modell, but that only takes images with `RGB` colorspace. I wonder how could I convert `ARFrame` `CVPixelBuffer` from `ycbcr` to `RGB` colorspace. I need `CVPixelBuffer` as a return type. I read that could be easily done with metal shaders, tho I want to use `SceneKit` for the rest of the project. Is there a solution without metal shaders? If not how could I use metal shaders for this while keeping `SceneKit`? Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: I _think_ Vision may be able to do this automatically, so that would be the easiest option (just pass the CVPixelBuffer to your Vision request object). Otherwise, vImage from Accelerate framework can do this.

Comment: Yes, Vision does this automatically.